# Mapping pandas dataframe by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a function that maps between 2 data-frames and returns a value based on conditions. One is a mapping DF, given below.

```py
data1 = {'variable':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
    'lower' : [0,100,200,0,5,1,4],
    'upper' : [100,200,300,5,10,4,8],
    'value' : [32,15,45,18,46,33,45]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['variable','lower', 'upper','value'])

print(df1)
```

[image: mapping table]

The other is the DF where I would apply the mapping, given below.

```py
data2 = {'A':[23,244,131,54,258,117,43,224],
    'B' : [0,2,1,9,7,4,6,3],
    'C' : [2,1,7,4,8,3,8,1]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['A','B', 'C'])

print(df2)
```

[image: data table]

What I am trying to do is create new column `mapped_A`, which will check the mapping `DF` for all rows with `A` and return the value based on the upper and lower ranges. For example the first row for `mapped_A` column will be `32` since `0 < 23 <= 100`. Same with columns `B` and `C`.

Desired Output:

[image: final table]

I can hard-code the logic something like the following, but there must be better ways to handle this.

```py
conditions = [(df2['A'] > 0) & (df2['A'] <= 100),
              (df2['A'] > 100) & (df2['A'] <= 200),
              (df2['A'] > 200) & (df2['A'] <= 300)]
choices = [32, 15, 45]

df2['mapped_A'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='null')
```

Comment: Your expected output is wrong for `B` and `C` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though use of `eval` is generally not recommended, it is handy to use in such scenarios where you have to build multiple conditions dynamically. You can build the string required to create those masking, then pass it to `eval` builtin while using `np.select`, iterating each columns in the second dataframe, and assigning the values to a new column.

```py
for col in df2:
    colValues = df1[df1['variable'].eq(col)]
    condition = '['+\
                ','.join(colValues.apply(lambda x:f"(df2[col]>{x['lower']}) & (df2[col]<={x['upper']})", 
                                         axis=1).values)+\
                ']'
    values = colValues['value']
    df2[f'maped_{col}'] = np.select(eval(condition), values, default=np.nan)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     A  B  C  maped_A  maped_B  maped_C
0   23  0  2     32.0      NaN     33.0
1  244  2  1     45.0     18.0      NaN
2  131  1  7     15.0     18.0     45.0
3   54  9  4     32.0     46.0     33.0
4  258  7  8     45.0     46.0     45.0
5  117  4  3     15.0     18.0     33.0
6   43  6  8     32.0     46.0     45.0
7  224  3  1     45.0     18.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I think ThePyGuy's solution is much more graceful but you could make a custom function that would save you the copy and pasting like so:

```
def maps2(d1, d2):
    out = {}
    for i in d2:
        condNums = [n for n in range(len(d1["variable"])) if d1["variable"][n] == i]
        n = "mapped_" + i
        out[n] = []
        for u in range(len(d2[i])):
            for o in condNums:
                if d2[i][u] >= d1["lower"][o] and d2[i][u] <= d1["upper"][o]:
                    out[n].append(d1["value"][o])

    return out
```

Also I changed your logic conditions in the `if` because you're desired output has conflicts with your original logic (the `>` is now `>=`).